# Java web application to convert xml to pdf

Tags: java, xml, web, web-applications, wkhtmltopdf

I want to make a web app executing this code, is it possible? If not please tell me a way to make a web app execute this java code

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.*;

public class Driver
{
 public static void main(String [] args) throws         TransformerConfigurationException,TransformerException,TransformerFactoryConfigurationError
    {
        (TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new    StreamSource(new File("people.xsl")))).transform(new StreamSource(new    File("book.xml")),new StreamResult(new File("HARSH.html")));
         ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "wkhtmltopdf HARSH.html 123.pdf");
           builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
           Process p = builder.start();
           BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
           String line;
           while (true) {
               line = r.readLine();
                if (line == null) { break; }
                System.out.println(line);}  
        }



}
```

Comment: Yes its quite possible. Just make a controller and call this code from that.Hit  that controller to execute it

Comment: Could you tell me how to make a controller. Google doesn't help much in this. Thanks

Comment: You can create a servlet and do things in that [lhttp://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm)